# How to configure Jenkins for Project that has multiple upstreams

Tags: jenkins

I have 4 Maven projects on Jenkins, 1 WAR and 3 JAR projects. The three JAR projects are dependencies for the WAR project.

I have set the 3 JAR projects in Jenkins to build on cron schedule every 30 minutes. The undesired result of which is the WAR project gets built every 5 minutes.

I would like instead the WAR project to be built only every 30 minutes, just like the JAR projects. I am aware of the option in Jenkins to **prevent building downstream** yet i am concerned of the adverse effect i would bring if i used this option as there could be a chance that the dependencies could break the WAR project.

Therefore, has someone come across this, and could share with me your practice for managing project builds on Jenkins. Thanks alot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, use release versions of JAR projects as dependencies for WAR project. In this case your WAR project should not be affected while you are working on SNAPSHOT versions of your JAR projects.

The only disadvantage is that you may need to perform lots of releases of JAR projects, but you can create them automatically each night / week / etc.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't go into detail why you need to build the jar jobs on cron bases and not just poll for changes. If you only build the jar projects when they changed, then you don't have any issues with the war project building unnecessarily.

Alternate approach is that since all jars build every 30 min, why not build the war also on a cron schedule? If you build the war every 30min, you are already cutting down on 2/3 of the builds.